# ratio "comparing to" instead of "to"

Tags: prepositions

Is the sentence below correct?

> It is calculated as the ratio of real errors **comparing to** all
>   detected errors.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the context. I'd say that you'd typically want to use "compared to" instead of "comparing to", since you're talking about two different sides of a ratio, but it's possible that certain technical contexts you might want to talk about a ratio between comparisons themselves, which is when you'd use "comparing to" for each comparison that you're making a ratio from.

Comment: comparing to here is not grammatical at all.

Comment: Yes. It should definitely be 'compared to'.

Answer (score -3):

Again this is from an academic journal.  Academics sometimes write strangely.  Academics sometimes invent new grammar, and new words, while writing anything within their academic context.  Academics also use certian types of grammar commonly, which no one else will ever use and which prevents some people with IQ below 115 or so from understanding the paper even if they wpuld normally be able to underatand it.  Even if you are an academic or a scientist and you plan to also do that kibd of thing in English, you still shouldn't write that way.  One thing that academics often to is insert extra small words, such as "are" and "to", where they do not belong.  While the specific sentence you've shown us here is a lesser example of that, and non-academics wouldn't easily be able to write it better without changing the entire structure.of the sentence or using multiple sentences instead....   non-academics would also most likely do exactly that if they for some reason had to tell someone about this ratio: They would use multiple sentences.  Or, more likely then thay, they would write all of the surrounding text in a different way, so that it is clear what they are referring to without having to try to explain several concepts at once within a single sentence.  A lot of users have posted questions in this area, quoting academic writings who's grammar is, basically, "incorrect".

In this case, the sentence is actually correct, just obstrusive.  "Obstrusive" has a similar meaning to be "concealed", and can be defined further by Google; pick an explanation that uses several sentences or more.

I just realized that a non-obstrustive way to write this sentence could also be to simply use "compared to".  "Compared to" is a normal combination of words and it is used 100% of the time when talking about things that are compared.  Everything I said above is still correvt, but in rhis particular case, using "compared to" will solve the problem.

To be even more in English and less in "weird academia grammatical territory" (although it's now no longer technically grammar that is the issue, after changing to "compared"), and to also be less obstrustive and to be understandable to anyone with an IQ over 85 or so who also knows what "ratio" means, you could say:

"That number refers to the ratio of the actual errors on top, to the number of errors that our software detected on the bottom."

"On the top" and "on the bottom" help accessibility to readers who's IQ is 92.  These could obviously be excluded.

If you know the number of actual errors, and you also have something that is meant to detect errors while knowing that, the most likely topic is a test of software that is meant to detect errors.  Obviously edit those words if the topic is something different.